# add a struct into struct linked list in C

Tags: c, list, struct

I need to write software that gets structure from the user (name, path and time) and then add the structure to the end of a linked list. I wrote two functions that work the problem that it only works in the first run, if the user tries to add another structure to the linked program the program crashes):
Can anyone help me understand what the problem is?
Thank you!
These are the structures I created:

```
// Frame struct
typedef struct Frame
{
    char* name;
    int duration;
    char* path;

} Frame;


// Link (node) struct
typedef struct FrameNode
{
    Frame* frame;
    struct FrameNode* next;
} FrameNode;
```

What are the functions:

```
FrameNode* addFrame(Frame frame)
{
    FrameNode* p = malloc(sizeof frame);
    printf("*** Creating a new frame ***\n");
    printf("Please insert frame path:\n");
    p->frame->path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);
    fgets(p->frame->path, 100, stdin);
    p->frame->path[strcspn(p->frame->path, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("Please insert frame duration <in miliseconds>:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &(p->frame->duration));
    getchar();
    printf("Please chooce a name for a new frame:\n");
    p->frame->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);
    fgets(p->frame->name, 100, stdin);
    p->frame->name[strcspn(p->frame->name, "\n")] = 0;
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        while (strcmp(list->frame->name, p->frame->name) == 0)
        {
            printf("The name is already taken, Please enter another name\n");
            fgets(p->frame->name, 100, stdin);
        }
    }
    p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}

FrameNode* insertAtEnd(FrameNode* list, Frame fr)
{
    FrameNode* tmp = addFrame(fr);
    if (list != NULL)
    {
        list = list->next;
    }
    list = tmp;
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `insertAtEnd` isn't adding the frame node to the end of the list. It adds it as the first or second item on the list, losing the link to the original second item (if any).

Comment: The `while (list != NULL)` loop in `addFrame` will be an infinite loop if `list != NULL` is true.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't compile.  https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/SparseToughSearchservice

Comment: What is this ```FrameNode* p = malloc(sizeof frame);```?

Comment: "insertAtEnd isn't adding the frame node to the end of the list. It adds it as the first or second item on the list, losing the link to the original second item (if any)." How can I link all the organs in the list without losing contact with the previous organs?

Comment: its my new code:

Comment: @אבילוי Your new version of `insertAtEnd` does not append anything to the list. It just returns the added frame node as the new list.

Comment: `FrameNode* insertAtEnd(FrameNode* list, Frame fr)` `{` `FrameNode* tmp = addFrame(fr);` `if (list != NULL)` `{` `FrameNode* end = list;` `while (end->next != NULL)` `{` `end = end->next;` `}` `end->next = tmp;` `}` `else` `{` `list = tmp;` `}` `return list;` `}`.

Comment: `addFrame` doesn't do anything with its parameter `frame` (apart from evaluating `sizeof(frame)` which is incorrect anyway).

Comment: In `addFrame`, the memory pointed to by `p` is uninitialized, so `p->frame` is an invalid pointer and `p->frame->path` is an invalid pointer dereference.

Comment: Now the program does not collapse but it retains only the first structure within the list ..

Comment: regarding: `p->frame->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);`  This allocates memory for 100 pointers rather than 100 characters.  Suggest 1) replace the 'magic' number 100  with a meaningful name, using a `#define` statement.  2) remove the expression: `sizeof( char *)`  3) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer. Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: There are LOTS of examples on stackoverflow.com on how to handle a linked list, including initialization, inserting a node, deleting a node, searching for specific data.  Strongly suggest searching for those many examples

Comment: regarding: `FrameNode* addFrame(Frame frame)`   How is this parameter generated?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here-

```
if (list != NULL)
    {
        list = list->next;
    }
    list = tmp;
```

Correct one is

```
while(list>next != NULL)
    {
        list = list->next;
     }
    list->next = tmp;
```

This will go to next until the last frame and add the new frame. In your code, it works first time because it only executes list=tmp. For other times, we are not going to the end of the list to add tmp. Note if instead of while. 
Also, in your code when list becomes NULL, we lose address of last frame, so we need the loop till `list>next!=NULL` instead of `list!=NULL`.

Comment: Okay this works but there is another problem now, I can't take another path for the third time:
This shows an error on this line:
fgets (p-> frame-> path, 100, stdin);

The error:
Exception thrown: write access violation.
* (__ imp__malloc (...)) was nullptr

Comment: Looks like a separate issue - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892589/exception-thrown-write-access-violation-this-was-nullptr)